# How can I set a specific decimal value for the output of pbinom()?

Tags: r

I have a single line of code below and the output displayed as below too. But how do I actually set the output to be 4 decimal places?

> 2*(1-pbinom(175, 240, 0.5))

output: 2.853273e-13

Comment: two things are at play here: (1) how R *displays* the numbers, try `pi` and realize that it has many more digits than are being shown; and (2) how many digits you retain in the number itself, ala rounding and such. If you want it to round to the nearest 4-digits, then use `round(., 4)`; if you want to change how it renders on the screen (never changes calculations), then use `options(digits=..)` as ThomasIsCoding's answer says.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `options(digits = ...)`

```
> options(digits = 5)

> 2 * (1 - pbinom(175, 240, 0.5))
[1] 2.8533e-13
```

Comment: Still in scientific notation though, which is not what I think of as being "4 decimal places"